# Unable to establish connection to 4D database via ODBC driver

Tags: odbc, dsn, 4d-database

I installed the ODBC for 4d server but could not work it! Did you ever get the ODBC driver to work?  I just installed it as well and cannot create a DSN that connects?

[image: Is the SQL Server started ? Client unable to establish connection.]

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid SO isn't a good place for resource requests, nor individual tech support... perhaps they have a support resource/forum of their own?

Comment: Please read [this community discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495) on urgent begging. Short version: don't do it please, it is not an acceptable way to address volunteers.

Answer (score 1):

The error dialog is stating that the client is unable to establish a connection and asking if the sql server is started. This indicates that the ODBC driver cannot communicate to the 4D Server on the ip/port you have specified. The most likely scenario is that *the SQL Server is not started* but it could also be a port conflict or firewall.

In order for the ODBC driver to connect to the 4D Server;

- the SQL Server must be started on 4D Server (i.e. [`START SQL SERVER`](http://doc.4d.com/4Dv15R4/4D/15-R4/START-SQL-SERVER.301-2825874.en.html))
- the SQL Server port (default 19812) must *not* be blocked by a firewall
- if using a non-standard port you must specify the port during DSN creation

Reminders:

- Make sure the version of the ODBC Driver matches the version of the 4D Server.
- At the DSN level you have selected 'Use SSL', so make sure the SQL Server is also [using ssl](http://doc.4d.com/4Dv15R4/4D/15-R4/Configuration-of-4D-SQL-Server.300-2818877.en.html#1613654)
- ODBC connections consume a 4D Client license in the absence of an Unlimited SQL license.

Comment: 1. I was done as above mentioned,but now I got another bug message "**cant send request header**".[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/IhfMk.png
 2. **I want to know something about 4D** ,can u suggest other tool instead of 4D odbc??
 3. How to convert 4d datas into CSV format????

Comment: Regarding your new error, make sure you are using the 4D Password System with a valid 4D user/password. If you have a firewall or antivirus try disabling it as a test. Regarding exporting data to CSV, you can use the [Export Dialog](http://doc.4d.com/4Dv15R4/4D/15-R4/Exporting-data-to-files.300-2880473.en.html) and configure the delimiters for a text export. There may be other formats available for export that may also work for you.